# sqlsrv in Registered PHP Streams

Tags: php, installation, sqlsrv

How can I get **sqlsrv** in Registered PHP Streams of my php installation?

I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_error() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\twickenham2013\class\sqlsrv.class.php on line 14
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Im facing the same issue.

Thats because the Registered PHP streams(`phpinfo()`) does not contain sqlsrv field.
this can be checked using the code

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

add the necessary .dll files in you xampp/php/ext. and edit the php.ini document.

To download the necessary .dll files and for more detailed installation instructions, see the PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.installation.php